# Having difficulty with Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET 4 book and entity framework database migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working my way through the book and the Sports Store examples, and generally finding it to be full of great, informative content.

But in Chapter 10 (listing 10-14), we walk though the simple act of adding some validation attributes to the product class, and this breaks the app because VS says the model backing the EFDbContext context has changed (we've only added the validation attributes), and suggests that we enable Code First Migrations to update the database.

The book moves forward without addressing the problem.  I am finding that I can't enable migrations because I get this:

```
PM> enable-migrations -enableautomaticmigrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'SportsStore.WebUI'.
```

There's no errata for the book, and I'm not sure how to make EF happy without doing the automatic migrations.

Does anyone have experience with this issue in the book, or know how I can move forward after changing my context backing model without migrations enabled?

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion, when ever I receive errors like this I always end up deleting my bin and obj folders in the project, rebuilding and then trying again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you set the default project to WebUI, when you open your package manager console it is set to your default project (WebUI) which does not have the database context, it is located on your Domain project, what you need to do is change the default project from WebUI to Domain, not on your solution settings but on your package manager console. heres a SS:
[image]

[image: Console]

Comment: Thank you oskar...  I thought I was doing this (via the package manager GUI), but I was forgetting to enable migrations, add a migration and update the database after associating EF with just domain project in the solution.  Once I did that, all was well.